# Shortcode for printing post titles

Tags: posts, shortcode

I am trying to make a shortcode to print a list of post titles. This is what I have so far:

```
function test( $atts , $content = null ){

    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3 );
    $lastposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $lastposts as $post )
    {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        echo the_title();
    } 
}
add_shortcode( 'test', 'test' );
```

The problem I have is that all it does is print the title of the page calling the shortcode rather than the titles of the posts. I am sure I am missing something basic but after two hours of trying to work it out I thought it was time to get another set of eyes to look at it.

Comment: Shortcode functions shouldn't actually output anyting, but return the desired output ([Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this has been answered and the answer solved the issue but I found it very poor for any newbie that want to learn WordPress so I give mine in the hope it will be better:

1. While `get_posts()` can do the job I would have used a simple
   query, for a secondary loop I prefer creating my own separate
   instance of the WP_Query
2. Engelen is right there's no use for
   `wp_reset_postdata()` here
3. The use of `$content` is also unecessary here, it's not a enclosing shortcode
4. A shortcode returns something. On no account it should output something on its own. That could trigger unpredictable bugs. It's quite the same with `add_filter()`
5. I know here it's just for test but generic names must be avoided for shortcodes because there is only one hook per shortcode so any shortcode that use the same name could override leading to unexpected results.

So for all these reasons I would recommand to do this instead :

```
add_shortcode( 'post_title', 'wpse_149667_post_title_sc' );
function wpse_149667_post_title_sc( $atts ){

    $args      = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3 );

    $lastposts = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $lastposts->have_posts() ) :

     $output    = '<ul>';

      while( $lastposts->have_posts() ) : $lastposts->the_post();

         $output .= '<li>'.get_the_title($lastposts->post->ID).'</li>';

      endwhile;

     $output .= '</ul>';

    else : 

        $output = 'There is currently no post to retrieve!';

    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();// more appropriate here

    return $output;
}
```

Hope this gives more explanations.

Answer (score -3):

Try like this:

```
function test( $atts , $content = null ){

    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3 );

    $lastposts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ( $lastposts as $post )  {
        echo get_the_title($post->ID);
    } 

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_shortcode( 'test', 'test' );
```

Comment: Matt, just a tip here, your answer is considered as code dumping. You should always explain your code does. Please [edit] your answer and add all relevant info

Comment: @PieterGoosen that maybe true but in true genius fashion he solved it.

Comment: Shortcode functions shouldn't actually output anyting, but return the desired output ([Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)). Furthermore, the `wp_reset_postdata` is unnecessary if you're not setting up new post data.

Comment: Value should be returned instead of printing. This causes issues if someone hooks with `the_content` or similar filters.